# Xamarin iOS Nuget conflict error when archiving in Release mode

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nuget, .net-standard

I have always used NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 packages in my iOS apps and I was able to archive them. But now I am getting warning while archiving:

Package 'Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms 0.0.3.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

How can I get rid of this error? I know that it will be fully compatible, but this warning stops the archiving process. Can't find any solutions so far

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had a compile error that i was indicated after I clicked to build instead of archive. It seemed to be Visual Studio error on Mac...

Answer (score 1):

That warning is from NuGet and not from Visual Studio for Mac.

To reproduce that warning about the assembly not being fully compatible the Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms 0.0.3.3 NuGet package can be installed into a .NET Standard 2.0 project.

There is no .NET Standard libraries in that NuGet package, just a Xamarin.iOS assembly and a Portable Class Library (PCL) assembly. So NuGet is saying that it treated the project as though it was compatible with .NET 4.6.1 and used the PCL assembly since there are no .NET Standard assemblies available.

To ignore this warning you can add it to the ignore warning list. You can do that in preferences or by editing the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Naxam.TopTabbedPage.Forms" Version="0.0.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The only problem in Visual Studio for Mac seems to be that adding the NoWarn to the PackageReference does not suppress the warning so you have to add it to the main property group.